# Looping around while using RxJava with Room

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-room

I had been trying to use RxJava with Room. The logic is simple, if there is no row for current date, I will create an instance and insert the row into the databse. The problem is that the row is being inserted but its acting like a loop. When I debug, the code goes to run insertTestType, it completes and then comes to the subscriber part of getTestModel and then the counter is 1 and then stops.

```
private void getTestModel() {
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        mCompositeDisposable.add(questionDatabase.questionDao().getTestByDate(date, testType)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(testModels -> {
                    if (testModels.size() > 0) {
                        testModel = testModels.get(0);
                    } else {
                        testModel = new TestModel(testType, date);
                        insertTestType();
                    }
                }, throwable -> Log.e("ErrorRx", "exception getModels")));
    }

    private void insertTestType() {
        Completable.fromAction(() -> questionDatabase.questionDao().insert(testModel))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError");
                    }
                });
    }
```

The database is,

```
@Insert
void insert(TestModel testModel);

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TestModel.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE " + TestModel.DATE + " = :date" + " AND testType " + "=:testType")
Flowable<List<TestModel>> getTestByDate(String date, TestType testType);
```

why its coming back to previous subscriber? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So when it comes to the subscriber part in `getTestModel ` the second time, `testModels.size()` returns 0, right?

Comment: I am really sorry that, I did something wrong with the queries. I have edited my questions. Its not looping but its goes back to the subscriber once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is running just as it should be :)
When you use `Flowable`, every time the data is updated the `Flowable` object will emit automatically, notifying all it's subscribers and that's why it invokes code from `subscribe` in your first method.
If you don't want such behaviour consider using `Maybe` - more informations [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)